# All Possible Pairs between Two Vectors in R Without Replacement

Tags: r

I'm looking to create a list of all the possible combinations of pairs between two vectors. As an example, if I have `v1 = c('A', 'B', 'C')` and `v2 = c('X', 'Y', 'Z')`, I'm NOT just looking for `expand.grid(v1, v2)`. I want to pair up each element of `v1` with an element of `v2` without replacement.

So I would want something like

AX, BY, CZ

AX, BZ, CY

AY, BX, CZ

AY, BZ, CX

AZ, BX, CY

AZ, BY, CX

Ideally, I'd love to also be able to label each combination (so AX, BY, CZ is one combination, AX, BZ, CY is the next, etc.). So the ideal output would be something like

```
my_df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C),
  var2 = c(X, Y, Z, X, Z, Y, Y, X, Z, Y, Z, X, Z, X, Y, Z, Y, X),
 match = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)  
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a permutation problem, which might be solved like below

```
> library(pracma)

> paste0(v1, t(perms(v2)))
 [1] "AZ" "BY" "CX" "AZ" "BX" "CY" "AY" "BZ" "CX" "AY" "BX" "CZ" "AX" "BY" "CZ"
[16] "AX" "BZ" "CY"
```

or

```
out <- data.frame(
  Var1 = v1,
  Var2 = c(t(perms(v2))),
  Match = ceiling(seq(factorial(length(v2)) * length(v2)) / length(v1))
)
```

which gives

```
> out
   Var1 Var2 Match
1     A    Z     1
2     B    Y     1
3     C    X     1
4     A    Z     2
5     B    X     2
6     C    Y     2
7     A    Y     3
8     B    Z     3
9     C    X     3
10    A    Y     4
11    B    X     4
12    C    Z     4
13    A    X     5
14    B    Y     5
15    C    Z     5
16    A    X     6
17    B    Z     6
18    C    Y     6
```